# How can I install 2 copies of git on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, git

Is it possible for me to install 2 copies of git on my Mac?
I have git 1.6.3.3 under /opt/local/bin/git, I would like to install a newer version of git in a different location on Mac OS X. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to compile it yourself or are you taking the dmg file?

Comment: I tried to compile myself but I want to switch between 2 version of git. git 1.6.3.3 for work, but git newer version at home. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any special reason why one would need both versions simultaniously?

Comment: Won't two versions of git still be compatible?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you are compiling yourself, then a simple

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/git-1.6.5.2
```

(and then `make`, `make install`) should suffice. Your binary files are now in `/opt/git-1.6.5.2/bin`. Obvously, you can change the directory to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the new version. They will still be compatible. (no guarentees on 2.0 whenever they make it, but there should be **no** incompatibilites between two 1.6.x versions)